Retrieve subdomain from request in next.js middleware.ts for edge cases
I try to retrieve the subdomain in the middleware.ts file for different edge cases:

subdomain shall be retrieved also when testing locally with localhost
subdomain shall be retrieved also when testing in development mode on vercel
base case: subdomain shall be retrieved when in production mode with my-domain.com

my current implementation does not capture those cases:
const { hostname, pathname } = request.nextUrl;
const parts = hostname.split('.');

let subdomain = '';

if (parts.length > 2) {
    subdomain = parts.slice(0, -2).join('.');
} else if (parts.length === 2) {
    subdomain = parts[0] || ''; // Handle case like 'subdomain.localhost'
}


When I test locally with logalhost and try to access: http://test.localhost:3000 the hostname is displayed as hostname http://localhost:3000/.
On vercel my domain is:
https://my-vercel-project-domain.vercel.app/
So it identifies my-vercel-project-domain as subdomain which shouldn't be the case.
I also tried to define the base domain as an environment variable but somehow always something doesn't work and it should not be that hard, right?
